# URL Rewriting with htaccess (Send first url to second) and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to send this url `example.com/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/` to this one `example.com/hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/`

I tried following with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^/?cow-courc-wood-alliance/ /hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/
```

See htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^/?cow-courc-wood-alliance/ /hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

## Hide version of wordpress in html file 
<files readme.html>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
```

Actually this is wordpress `example.com/hotel/`  and `hotel` is one page in admin thats why it is `example.com/hotel/`.

I have added Codeigniter in wordpress root in folder `/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/`. This is folder `cow-courc-wood-alliance` and `register` is controller. Now i want to run my url here `example.com/hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/`

Comment: That looks fine. What is the error you're getting? Do you have other rules before this?

Comment: I am getting 404 error

Comment: I just want to redirect first url to second but hotel is page and i want to redirect from example.com/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/  to example.com/hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/

Comment: Everything is working fine i just want one line code to redirect from one position to other i have tried redirect but that will not work. Sorry other htaccess is not related to it.

Comment: I am glad that you want to see it. but sorry i can not share it.

Comment: this is new task for me to redirect from one url to other. And there no hotel in htaccess before this not redirection. i can just share this only

Comment: @anubhava. Please see it

Comment: ok this explains... WP doesn't allow internal rewrites. You will need to use WP rewrite API (php code in your theme)

Comment: Actually this is  wordpress example.com/hotel/ and hotel is one page in admin thats why it is example.com/hotel/, I have added Codeigniter in wordpress root in folder cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/ . This is folder "cow-courc-wood-alliance" and "register" is controller. Now i want to run my url here example.com/hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/

Comment: @anubhava . I added comment. Sorry to say

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with WordPress. This is because WP have the logic of the URL's so if you redirect or rewrite something and WordPress do not know it you get an 404 error.

You have to **change the URL** to e.g. `/hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/` **in WordPress** and than you can redirect incoming URL's like this `/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register/` one to the new location:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^/?cow-courc-wood-alliance/(.*)$ /hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

### EDIT

You did not tell us that you use some other Framework as well. Now with the new Information you have to change the htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Rewrite incoming URLs like /hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance/register to the Framework Folder
    RewriteRule ^/?hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance(/.*)?$ /cow-courc-wood-alliance/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    # Folder cow-courc-wood-alliance should not go to Wordpress
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?cow-courc-wood-alliance(/.*)?$ [NC]
    # Folder /hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance should not go to Wordpress
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?hotel/cow-courc-wood-alliance(/.*)?$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I can not add another register page in wordpress. there is already one in it. This ur is different

Comment: You did not give us this inflamtion in your Question... see my Edit

Comment: Its not working for me but thanks for your help. I  need to find another way.